# Loading an javafx image from rest resource (url not ending with jpg,png...)

Tags: image, rest, javafx

I have problems loading an image from an http resource into `javafx.scene.image.Image`.

I am using the constructor `new Image(url)`. In my case the url is not ending with an image extension. In this cases just nothing is loaded but there is also no error:

```
new Image("http://localhost/some.jpg") // this works
new Image("http://localhost/getImage") // not working, no error
```

So is there a way to load images from such rest resources?
If not i have to use an http client and fiddle around with In/Outputstreams right?

Comment: I can't replicate your issue (images served by web servers over http will load fine for me, regardless of the extension specified in the url and if no content type is returned by the web server - OS X 10.9.5, tomcat 9m3, Java8u72).  My guess is that the Image code does a deep inspection of the returned content to determine the appropriate decoding algorithm to use (e.g. png or jpg decoding).

Comment: very odd, in meantime i am using an http client api with this all works fine.